# Why Can't I Click Link?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I was wondering if anyone knows why I can't click the "Get Directions" link at the top of the page.
http://progressivespineandsports.com/

There is a target of blank attribute on the link but I don't think that this has anything to do with the link not working.

Comment: simple-IT IS NOT A LINK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
.block.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

to your css, for a **quick** fix.

The problem is that the `#content` div lays upon/above your header div.

Comment: LOL, That z-index gets me everytime. Thanx :) I'll upvote you and accept this as the answer as soon as the system lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Because `div.block.header` has a height of 0, all its children are float. So `div#content` stacks above the link, prevents you from clicking the header link.

Add `overflow: hidden` to `div.block.header`, or other clearfix tricks.

Comment: Thanx Leo, but the answer had to do with the z-index.

Comment: @AlexWilliams Have you tried my solution? There're always more than one approach in web dev.

Comment: This header code was written very poorly by the theme's creator, in my opinion, an I just wanted a quick fix so I patched the first code that worked. Thanx for your input Sir.